# File Input control get Images path bind in array and show them in ngfor loop?

Tags: angular

I was trying a approach to get multiple files from file input control and iterate those files get their path and store them in array and in html i wanted to show all multiple files here is my code.

```
pictureschanged(input: any) {
    const fileList = input.target.files;
    this.testimage = this.sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(input.target.value) ;
    console.log(this.testimage);
    if (fileList != undefined) {
      this.imageColllection = fileList;
      this.imageCount = fileList.length;
      let arr = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.imageColllection.length; i++) {
        let file = this.imageColllection[i];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload =  this.uploadImage.bind(this);
        // (e): void => {
        //   arr.push(e.target['result']);
        //   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        // }
      }
      console.log(this.imageColllection);
      // reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      // var path = (window.URL).createObjectURL(fileList[key]);
      // console.log(path);
    }
  }
```

My html code

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="" class="control-label col-sm-3">
            Upload picture:
          </label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-2" *ngFor="let file of imageColllection">
                <div class="picture-holder">
                  <img [src]="testimage" alt="" class="image-prop">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12" [ngClass]="{'col-xs-12':imageCount===0,'col-xs-10':imageCount===1,'col-xs-8':imageCount===2,'col-xs-8':imageCount===3}">
                <div class="dropZoneOverlay" (change)="pictureschanged($event)" #imageTemp>
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
                  </i>
                  <input type="file" multiple accept="image/*" class="control-custom FileUpload">
                  <!-- <div *ngIf="Pictures.touched && Pictures.invalid">
                  Please provide only 3 pictures
                </div> -->
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

here as you see I m able to get files in `picturechanged()` method but not able to get their path and if i get path angular wont load it localy because angular prevents local resources not allowed,how can i achieve that functionality.The following task need to do

1)get the paths of files .

2)bind those path to image src property .

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, how you can achieve it :

> Component :

```
urls = [];
onSelectFile(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        var filesAmount = event.target.files.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = (event) => {
                  console.log(event.target.result);
                   this.urls.push(event.target.result); 
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

> Template :

```
<img *ngFor='let url of urls'  [src]="url" height="200"> <br/>

<input type='file' (change)="onSelectFile($event)" multiple>
```

---

Here is the link to working demo :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-file-upload-preview